# Genetic sequences(triplets)

Tags: c, string, document

I had to write a program that would read a string and output all genetic sequences(triplets) of letters A,T,C,G that are repeated the most throughout the string. If some triplets are repeated the same amount of times, the one which is first in order in the string is outputted. If there is any other character or letter in the string except A,T,C,G then the program should print an error and finish. I have code that usually works and does well in sorting, but some inputs don't and I can't seem to figure out why.

for these it doesn't work, I hardcoded them in this code so I can point them out:

```
if (strncmp(input, "CTA", 3) == 0) {
        printf("GCT\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

```
    for (int i = 0; input[i + 17] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (strncmp(&input[i], "AAAAACCCCCGGGGGTCTTCT", 20) == 0) {
            printf("TCT\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

**This is the main code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH 1000

int isValid(char ch) {
    return (ch == 'A' || ch == 'T' || ch == 'C' || ch == 'G');
}

void markLettersUsed(int usedIndices[], int start, int end);

int isLetterUsed(int usedIndices[], int index) {
    for (int i = 0; usedIndices[i] != -1; i++) {
        if (usedIndices[i] == index) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char filename[] = "genetski_kod.txt";
    char input[MAX_LENGTH];

    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Pogresan format\n");
        return 0;

    }

    int ch;
    int i = 0;

    if ((ch = fgetc(file)) == EOF) {
        printf("Pogresan format\n");
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && i < sizeof(input) - 1) {
        if (!isValid(ch)) {
            printf("Pogresan format\n");
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }
        input[i++] = ch;
    }

    input[i] = '\0';

    fclose(file);

    if (strncmp(input, "CTA", 3) == 0) {
        printf("GCT\n");
        return 0;
    }

    int maxCount = 0;
    int mostFrequentTripletStartIndex = -1;

     

    for (int i = 0; input[i + 17] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (strncmp(&input[i], "AAAAACCCCCGGGGGTCTTCT", 20) == 0) {
            printf("TCT\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    int usedIndices[MAX_LENGTH];

    for (int i = 0; input[i + 2] != '\0'; i++) {
        int count = 1;

        memset(usedIndices, -1, sizeof(usedIndices));

        for (int j = i + 3; input[j - 2] != '\0' && input[j - 1] != '\0' && input[j] != '\0' && input[j + 1] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (input[i] == input[j - 2] && input[i + 1] == input[j - 1] && input[i + 2] == input[j]) {
                if (!isLetterUsed(usedIndices, j - 2) && !isLetterUsed(usedIndices, j - 1) && !isLetterUsed(usedIndices, j)) {
                    count++;
                    markLettersUsed(usedIndices, j - 2, j);
                }
            }
        }

        if (count > maxCount) {
            maxCount = count;
            mostFrequentTripletStartIndex = i;
        }
    }

    if (maxCount > 0) {
        printf("%c%c%c\n", input[mostFrequentTripletStartIndex],
               input[mostFrequentTripletStartIndex + 1],
               input[mostFrequentTripletStartIndex + 2]);
    } else {
        printf("Pogresan format\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

void markLettersUsed(int usedIndices[], int start, int end) {
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        usedIndices[i] = i;
    }
}
```

This is one of the tests for the program:

```
FILE* file = fopen("genetic_code.txt", "w");
fputs("AAAAACCCCGGGGGGTCTTCTAAA", file);
fclose(file);
_main();

file = fopen("genetic_code.txt", "w");
fputs("AAAAACCCCCGGGGGTCTTCT", file);
fclose(file);
_main();

/* Program Input/Output */
Expected output(s):
GGG
TCT

Or:
GGGTCT

Your program output:
*blank*
```

Comment: What does `_main();` do? It looks like you're writing to `genetic_code.txt` but the program expects to read from `genetski_kod.txt`.

Comment: Make a table that uses codons as the keys and the value is a struct containing the count of matches for that codon and the index of the first instance. Then you can loop through that looking for the entry with the highest count and lowest index.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes it writes in in because every test needs a different genetski_kod.txt so it just rewrites in one file

Comment: @eminbihh If you write to `genetic_code.txt` and then try to read from `genetski_kod.txt` it will always fail (if `genetski_kod.txt` doesn't exist) or read the same thing over and over again. You need to write to the file you later read from.

Answer (score 2):

When I tested out your program with a test file containing the first genetic test string, I first refined the diagnostic output to better locate where the issue was occurring.  The issue was happening in the character read loop.

```
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && i < sizeof(input) - 1)
    {
        if (!isValid(ch))
        {
            printf("Char - Pogresan format: %d\n", ch);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }
        input[i++] = ch;
    }
```

Adding in information about the questionable character highlighted that the reading of the characters was coming across a "newline" character (ASCII value "10").

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/DNA/bin/Release$ ./DNA 
Char - Pogresan format: 10
```

Adding in a test to ignore "newline" characters, I was able to acquire a DNA pattern output.

```
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF && i < sizeof(input) - 1)
    {
        if (ch == '\n')     /* Skip newline character */
            continue;
        if (!isValid(ch))
        {
            printf("Char - Pogresan format: %d\n", ch);
            fclose(file);
            return 0;
        }
        input[i++] = ch;
    }
```

Then, the first test string was entered into the text file.

```
AAAAACCCCGGGGGGTCTTCTAAA

craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/DNA/bin/Release$ ./DNA 
GGG
```

Then, the second test was entered and the program was rerun.

```
AAAAACCCCCGGGGGTCTTCT

craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/DNA/bin/Release$ ./DNA 
TCT
```

The main takeaway is be aware that your test may need to be fault tolerant when it comes to encountering formatting and line control characters.

Comment: Yes, it will work but it works just because it's hardcoded for the second example that you tried, when you remove the hardcoded part it won't work and it will output AAA. That's why I need help with why it acts like that for this example.

Comment: And I also want to remove the two examples that I solved by making an if statement and knowing what a certain test expects. I want to fix that so it would do it on its own without the two if statements.